# Negative Passion - What is a word or phrase for an effort someone puts themselves into greatly, but is not enthusiastic about?

Tags: single-word-requests

A noun.

For example, I am obligated to my job, and spend a lot of time outside of work thinking about it, but am not very enthused, emotional, or ecstatic about it - so I cannot say it's a passion of mine.

It's not just a hobby -- as that has neutral connotations and potentially excludes work and other obligations.

More of a negative passion?

Comment: It looks like it is a question of “sense of duty”.

Comment: "(A)n idea or thought that continually preoccupies or intrudes on a person's mind" is called an **obsession**.

Comment: What does "obligated to your job" mean? That is not English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A painful duty, an onerous task, an unwanted burden, a cheerless role,  empty work, meaningless toil, a pleasureless responsibility, a hard slog, miserable drudgery, menial labor.

You could also say, it’s just scut work to pay the bills, to put food on the table, to pay the rent, to keep the kids from going barefoot.

Comment: A pleasure-less responsibility is the closest feeling I could use to describe it. Thanks for all the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

In AmE we use the word "**job**" to describe tasks we must perform dutifully - despite lack of enthusiasm - whether or not there is pay involved.

As in: "Drinking that nasty protein shake everyday is turning into a ***job***"

(So, the simplest answer is actually found in your explanation of your question.)

Comment: It's more than a duty. It's a pleasureless passion. I want to be good at my job, even though it's more negative than positive. There's more emotion I'd like to convey with the word.

Answer (score 0):

I think compulsion is a good word that describes what you are talking about.

Via Merriam-Webster:

> **[Compulsion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compulsion)** *Noun*
>
> an irresistible persistent impulse to perform an act (such as
>   excessive hand washing)

Unlike Duty or Obsession (which can be positive) this generally carries negative connotation.